# JS crashes sometimes with Timer scramble

Tags: javascript, oop, browser, crash, prototype

My Javascript timer is for people with a rubiks cube with generates a scramble (nevermind all this, but just to tell you I'm generating after each solve a new scramble will be generated) and my scrambles do actually have a `while (true)` statement. So that does crash my script, but it 95/100 times stops just before the script crashes but I don't wanna have any times.

Let me explain a bit more detailed about the problem.

**Problem: javascript crashes because my script takes too long to generate a scramble.**

Below you have 3 functions I use.
This function generates a scramble with the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

```
Timer.prototype.generateScramble = function(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
};
```

This function validates the input e.g. I receive an array as the following:

Here I only have to check the first character. That's why I use the seconds `[ ]` notation. I don't want people get an F with an F2 e.g.

```
var scr = ["F","R","U","B","L","D","F2","R2","U2","B2","L2","D2","F'","R'","U'","B'","L'","D'"]

Timer.prototype.validateScramble2 = function(array) {
    var last = array.length-1;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        if (array[i][0] == array[i+1][0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-2; i++) {
        if (array[i][0] == array[i+2][0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (array[0][0] == [last][0]) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

The above functions are just waiting to be called. Well in the function below I use them.

```
Timer.prototype.updateScramble2 = function(scrambleArr, len, type) {
    var self = this;
    var scramble = '', j, updatedArr = [];

    while (updatedArr.length < len) {
        j = (Math.floor(Math.random() * scrambleArr.length));
        updatedArr.push(scrambleArr[j]);
    }

    while (!self.validateScramble2(updatedArr)) {
        updatedArr = self.generateScramble(updatedArr);
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < updatedArr.length; i++) {
        scramble += updatedArr[i] + ' ';
    }

    scrambleDiv.innerHTML = scramble;
};
```

I assume you guys understand it but let me explain it briefly.
The first `while-loop` adds a random value from the given array(scrambleArr) into a new array called `updatedArr`.

The next `while-loop` calls the `validateScramble2()` function if there isn't in an array F next to an F2.

The `for-loop` adds them into a new variable added with a whitespace and then later we show the scramble in the div: `scrambleDiv.innerHTML = scramble;`

**What do I need know after all this information?**

Well I wanna know why my `updateScramble2()` functions lets my browser crash every time and what I do wrong and how I should do it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but from the way your code looks, I think you have an infinite loop going on. It appears as if `validateScramble2` always returns `false` which causes your second loop in `updateScramble2` to perpetually run.

I suggest you insert a breakpoint in your code and inspect the values. You could also insert `debugger;` statements in your code, works the same way. Open dev tools prior to doing these.

---

A suggestion is instead of using loops, use a timer. This breaks up your loop into asynchronous iterations rather than synchronous. This allows the browser breathing space for other operations. Here's an example of a `forEachAsync`:

```
function forEachAsync(array, callback){
  var i = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    callback.call(null, array[i]);
    if(++i >= array.length) clearInterval(timer);
  }, 0);
}

forEachAsync([1,2,4], function(item){
  console.log(item);
});
```

You can take this further and use Promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: It does return true a lot. it takes random values from array A and puts in into a new array called B. (for example) and then it checks if there is no F near an F2. But sometimes it takes a bit too long I guess and then the browser says: "alright we timeout the script. It takes too long. We think it's an infinite loop."

Comment: @KimKoomen Added example of an asynchronous loop using timers.